# Yii relational table for CListView action index

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In my web application view I need to display columns from two different related tables,for index action
But I am getting this error , Which I am unable to figure out, How should I resolve any body pls help

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

In this line

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->producerOfferUserRelation->name); ?>
     <br />
```

My code for the model

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                'producerOfferVegetableRelation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Vegetable', 'vegetable_id'),
                'producerOfferUserRelation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
                'producerOfferVegetableViaCodeRelation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Vegetable', 'code'),
        );
    }


    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'producerOfferUserRelation.name' => 'Offered By',
            'producerOfferVegetableRelation.name' => 'Offered Vegetable',
            'offered_qty' => 'Offered Qty(/KG)',
            'unit_cost' => 'Unit Cost(RS/KG)',
            'unit_delivery_cost' => 'Unit Delivery Cost(RS/KM)',
            'offered_date' => 'Offered Date',
            'booking_status' => 'Booking Status',
            'booked_by' => 'Booked By',
            'available_days' => 'Available Days',
        );
    }
```

My index action in controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('ProducerOffer');

    $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

My code for the index.php and _view.php

```
<div class="container">

    <legend>
        <h2>Producer offer/h2>
    </legend>
    <div>
        <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code for the _view.php

```
<?php

?>

<div class="view">



    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('producerOfferUserRelation.name')); ?>:</b>

    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->producerOfferUserRelation->name); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('producerOfferVegetableRelation.name')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->producerOfferVegetableRelation->name); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('unit_cost')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->unit_cost); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('unit_delivery_cost')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->unit_delivery_cost); ?>
    <br />



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data you are trying to access through relation does not exist.

```
$data->producerOfferUserRelation
```

this line returns null because corresponding data does not exist in producerOdderUser table. So when you write

```
$data->producerOfferUserRelation->name
```

basically you are trying like

```
$data->null->name
```

thats why you are getting the error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```